# How to access rest point from Python that requires a google sign on?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, oauth-2.0, google-api-python-client

I am trying to do a:

```
response = requests.post(url, json=payload)
```

call in Python to a site, but get "unauthorized" response. If I use a browser, I get redirected first to "https://accounts.google.com/v3/signin/identifier/..." to authenticate (which I do) before allowed on website. Is there a way I can do this programmatically through Python. Ideally without browser?
Thanks ahead for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which web site you want make a request and what you want to do with it.

If you want to have some data from the web site you can check aboutBeautifulSoup and how to login with google, you can check this (answer)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47855539/login-to-a-website-with-google-using-beautifulsoup-and-python-2-7]

If you want to access of a specific route from the website API check how to authenticate with Google in OAuth2.